# Return a float value when using int parameters C

Tags: c

I have this issue where I need to print `float` number while I use `int` parameters in function.

```
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight) {
  return (stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight);
}
```

I'm checking it by using:

```
printf("%.4f\n", lift_a_car(2, 80, 1400));
```

It only returns 0.0000.

Comment: cast one value to `float`before the calculation

Comment: Unless you're targeting a severely memory-constrained target system, there's almost never a need to use `float` these days. Use `double` instead.

Comment: There's also no need to mark any of the function arguments as `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this is, that in C every calculation is made with the most complex type in use. In your case this type is `int`, because `int`/`int` is treated as an integer division. The same for the addition and multiplication. To fix this, you have to cast the integers to floats explicitly, otherwise it will only be done at the end.

Your code `return (stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight);` equals the following operation:

```
int t1 = stick_length * human_weight; // 2 * 80 = 160
int t2 = car_weight * human_weight;   // 1400 * 80 = 112000
int t3 = t1 / t2; (integer division)  // 160 / 112000 = 0
return (float) t3;
```

But what you want is to do this:

```
return ((float) stick_length*human_weight)/((float) car_weight+human_weight);
// or
return (float) (stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight);
```

This will be evaluated like:

```
float t1 = (float) stick_length * human_weight; // 2.0f * 80 = 160.0f
float t2 = (float) car_weight + human_weight;   // 160.0f * 140 = 112000.0f
float t3 = t1 / t2; (floating division)         // 160.0f / 112000.0f = 0.0014...
// or
int t1 = stick_length * human_weight;           // 2 * 80 = 160
int t2 = car_weight + human_weight;             // 160 * 140 = 112000
float t3 = (float) t1 / t2; (floating division) // 160.0f / 140 = 0.0014...
```

Comment: "you have to cast the integers to floats explicitly" --> cast is one way., not the only way.  Could use  `float sl = stick_length; return sl * human_weight / (car_weight + human_weight);` for example.

Answer (score 0):

The calculation

```
(stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

is an all integer calculation with an integer result. You should cast at least one of the variables or intermediate results to a floating point value.

Like for example

```
(float) (stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

That will convert the result of `stick_length*human_weight` into a `float` value, making the division a floating-point operation with a floating-point result.

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer of [our programming dude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558/some-programmer-dude) is correct, it looks quite dangerous:

Indeed, this is integer arithmetic:

```
(stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

Indeed, this is floating point arithmetic:

```
(float) (stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

But why? Simply because typecasting precedes multiplication (or division): it's the same as:

```
((float) (stick_length*human_weight))/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

But beginners might not be aware of that and might start to do stuff like:

```
(float) ((stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight))
```

=> which will again give a bad result.

Therefore I would propose to perform a typecasting, as narrow as possible, something like:

```
((float) stick_length*human_weight)/(car_weight+human_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type-casting while returning the calculated value should help you. Otherwise, you are returning 160/1480 which is 0 unless type-casting is not applied.

This code should help:

```
float lift_a_car(const int stick_length, const int human_weight, const int car_weight) 
{
  return ((float)(stick_length*human_weight))/((float)(car_weight+human_weight));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP's code is doing integer division and so gets a truncated quotient.

---

For fun, a non-floating point, cast-less, integer approach. Useful in small processors where FP support is expensive.

```
void print_lift_a_car(int stick_length, int human_weight, int car_weight) {
  // Use wider types like long or long long to avoid overflow.
  // Scale integer math by 10000 as "%.4f" was desired.
  long num = 10000L * stick_length * human_weight;
  long den = 0L + car_weight + human_weight;  // A long instead of an int addition.
  long ratio = (num + den/2) / den; // Rounded division.
  printf("%ld.%04ld\n", ratio/10000, ratio%10000);
}
```

May also want to handle `den == 0` and `ratio < 0` with additional code.